# Closure not returning the desired output

Tags: function, go, closures

I am wondering why my function does not return the lines. I'm using closures and my goal is to display each line from a decoded text. I was able to achieve this using Python.

Here's my Python code:

```
def get_line():
    lines = base64_decode()
    index = 0

    def closure():
        nonlocal index

        def go_next():
            nonlocal index

            next_line = line[index]
            index += 1

            return next_line

        if index != len(lines):
            return go_next()
        else:
            index = 0
            return go_next()

    return closure
```

Here's my Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func base64Decode() string {
    str := "REDACTED"
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(str)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error:", err)
    }

    return string(data)
}

func getLine(str string) func() string {
    i := 0
    lines := strings.Split(str, "\n")

    return func() string {
        if i != len(lines) {
            nextLine := lines[i]

            i++
            return nextLine
        }

        return ""
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getLine(base64Decode()))
}
```

What happens when I run this is it only prints: `0x1095850` instead of `This is the first line` from the text.

Comment: Your function returns a function. You're printing the function (what you see is its address) instead of calling the function and printing its return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to invoke the function:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(getLine(base64Decode())())
}
```